# Yeoman causes obscure double-print output when run as External Tool from WebStorm

Tags: webstorm, yeoman

I am trying to wire up various `yeoman` generators as `External Tools` in `JetBrains WebStorm` (as well as `JetBrains Rider`) and am experiencing a very peculiar problem with the output.

On generators that take any kind of input, there is all sorts of cattywompus output, specifically duplicated output that is obtusely fragmented.

Thinking this might be a problem with the terminal encoding, I've turned the encoding to `UTF-8` in the `*.vmoptions` file as told by support by adding `-Dfile.encoding=UTF-8` to the file and rebooting.

[image: webstorm vm options]

But it doesn't seem to matter what I do, or how I configure it - when I configure a yeoman generator as an external tool, I get obscure output. I've captured the phenomenon in a screen cast here;

### [VIDEO OF THE PROBLEM OCCURRING](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1sS1UJrR5MgLkp5m-NYcj_fda49f-u7Ub/view)

I have also just included a screenshot, for those who would rather not watch the video.

[image: DUPLICATED OUTPUT IN YEOMAN]

These are the settings I'm using for the external tools, in their respective order;

[image: EXTERNAL TOOL SETTINGS]
[image: EXTERNAL TOOL SETTINGS]

For good measure, [here is a repository of the exact generator I am using in the video and screenshots](https://github.com/ciel/generator-stackoverflow-example); The easiest way to make this available is to run

```
npm install
npm link
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is caused by ANSI sequences processing in external tools console. Yo generator uses [inquirer.js](https://github.com/SBoudrias/Inquirer.js/) module that, in turn, uses some special [ANSI escape sequences](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ANSI_escape_code) to format the output, namely

`CSI 8D` **Cursor Back**
`CSI 8C` **Cursor Forward**
`CSI 2K` **clear entire line**

these sequences are not currently supported; please follow [IDEA-149959](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-149959) and linked tickets for updates

Comment: Thank you very much for the link to the YouTrack topic. So there really is nothing I can do about this, at the moment?